# git autodeploy script within post-receive hook on ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, deployment, gitosis

I have an autodeploy bash script to get updated repo to /tmp in 'post-receive' hook on gitosis

> #!/bin/bash
>
> > PWD=$PWD
> >
> > REPO_NAME=${PWD##/*/}
> >
> > cd /tmp
> >
> > git clone git@atom-desktop:$REPO_NAME

But anytime when I push repository I got error like this:

> Host key verification failed.
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   error: hooks/post-receive exited with error code 128

How to cope with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
git clone --local $REPO_NAME
```

As git also supports cloning from local directories:
[git-clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> For local respositories, also
>   supported by git natively, the
>   following syntaxes may be used:
>
> /path/to/repo.git/
>
> file:///path/to/repo.git/
>
> These two syntaxes are mostly
>   equivalent, except the former implies
>   --local option.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a key mismatch in the SSH connection from wherever /tmp is and atom-desktop. What happens if you try to SSH from the machine that /tmp is located at to atom-desktop?

Comment: /tmp folder is located on atom-desktop, if I try to do 'touch sample_file' in the same post-receive script, it is created by 'git' user as a file owner without any problem, I though this may be key mismatch, but how to fix that ?

Comment: This is why I said "what happens if you SSH". The error should give you an indication as to what you need to do. If it does not, try removing ~/.ssh/known_hosts. That is where public key fingerprints are stored.

Comment: when I log as 'git' user (with disable password) and do ssh://git@192.168.0.6/home/git/repositories/myproject,I am asked about password, but when i do the same from other pc in local network, it works without prompting, maybe I should add 'git' user rsa pub key somewhere ?

Comment: Sounds like you have set up passwordless SSH, but not on the machine you need it to work from. See here for a very quick tutorial one how to set it up (I forget every time!): http://blogs.translucentcode.org/mick/archives/000230.html